# Sum of complex roots of quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics

How to find the sum of the complex roots of the quadratic equation $$px^2+qx+r=0$$ if $r>p>0$, and $p,q,r \in\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: sum of roots $$=-\frac qp$$ for all cases

Comment: See [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas).

Comment: If $p, q, r \in \mathbb{R}$ then all complex roots come in conjugate pairs which means their sum will be $-\frac{q}{p}$.  Now, if some of those are complex numbers, then this may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation is

$px^2+qx+r=0, \; \text{with} \; r > p > 0 \tag{1}$

and $p, q, r \in \Bbb R$, the real numbers.  If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the roots of (1), then they are also roots of

$x^2+\dfrac{q}{p}x+\dfrac{r}{p} = 0, \tag{2}$

which is just (1) divided through by $p \ne 0$.  $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ being roots of (2) implies we have the factorization

$x^2+\dfrac{q}{p}x+\dfrac{r}{p} = (x - \rho_1)(x - \rho_2) = x^2 - (\rho_1 + \rho_2)x + \rho_1 \rho_2, \tag{3}$

and if we compare the coefficients of like powers of $x$, i.e., of $x^0 = 1, x^1 = x$ and $x^2$, we see that

$\rho_1 + \rho_2 = -\dfrac{q}{p} \tag{4}$

and

$\rho_1 \rho_2 = \dfrac{r}{p}. \tag{5}$

(4) and (5) hold in the both the cases real and complex roots.  In fact, it is easy to see that they hold over any field, i.e. when $0 \ne p, q, r \in \Bbb F$ an arbitrary field in which (1) has a root.

***Note Added in Edit:*** Returning to the case $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$, $r >p > 0$, with $\rho_1, \rho_2 \in \Bbb C$ but $\rho_1, \rho_2 \notin \Bbb R$, note that in this event we have $\rho_2 = \bar {\rho}_1$, i.e. $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are complex conjugates.Thus by (5),

$\vert \rho_1 \vert^2 = \rho_1 \bar{\rho_1} = \rho_1 \rho_2 = \dfrac{r}{p}, \tag{6}$

and likewise

$\vert \rho_2 \vert^2 = \dfrac{r}{p}, \tag{7}$

so that

$\vert \rho_1 \vert = \vert \rho_2 \vert = \sqrt{\dfrac{r}{p}}. \tag{8}$

Thus

$\vert \rho_1 \vert + \vert \rho_2 \vert = 2\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{p}} > 2 \tag{9}$

since $r > p$.  This is option (d) in user140013's comment.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: absolutely right .

Comment: @user140013:  thanks!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 0):

$$
x = \frac{-q \pm \sqrt{q^2 - 4pr}}{2p}
$$

Regardless:

$$
\frac{-q + \sqrt{q^2 - 4pr}}{2p} + \frac{-q - \sqrt{q^2 - 4pr}}{2p} =\frac{-2q + \sqrt{q^2 - 4pr} - \sqrt{q^2 - 4pr}}{2p}= \frac{-2q + 0}{2p} = -\frac{q}{p}
$$

**edit**

OK, I think I understand the problem now.  For there to be complex roots, we have:

$$
q^2 < 4pr \rightarrow |q| < 2\sqrt{pr}
$$

We need to handle two different cases:

1. q > 0
  Here we have $-\frac{q}{p} = -\frac{|q|}{p}$.  Since $|q| < 2\sqrt{pr}$, this gives a bound from a "small" negative number.  The actual $q$ must be smaller, and thus must be a
  *smaller*
  negative which is
  *really*
  a larger number (a more positive number), thus we get:
  $$
  \text{sum} > -2\frac{\sqrt{pr}}{p}\rightarrow \text{sum} > -2\sqrt{\frac{r}{p}}
  $$
  Since $r > p$, $\sqrt{\frac{r}{p}} > 1$.  This gives a minimum (negative) number of $-2$.  Since the sum should be greater, this means we indeed have $\text{sum} > -2$.
2. $q \leq 0$
  In this case $-\frac{q}{p} = \frac{|q|}{p}$.  Now we need a legitimately smaller number (smaller positive number):
  $$
  \text{sum} < 2\sqrt{\frac{r}{p}} < 2
  $$

This would suggest that the sum is between $-2$ and $+2$.

Comment: But choices to this question are as : a)equal to 1           b)equal to 2      c)less than 2 but not equal to 1           d)greater than 2

Comment: The sum of the complex roots could be $0$ if $q^2 \geq 4pr$.  I don't see anything in the question that requires this though.

Comment: Sorry I gave you wrong question mod(one root)+mod(other root) is asked

Comment: @user140013:  you might consider editing your question if it is wrong as stated.  Wrong meaning, not what you (apparently) intended, judging from your comment.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm still questioning my reasoning on what I assumed to be the question.  I agree though, the question needs to be clarified (a lot).  The sum could be less than $-2$.  For instance $r = 4p$ and $q < 4p$.  So maybe $p = 1, r = 4, q = 3$.  This would give $-\frac{q}{p} = -\frac{3}{1} < -2$.

Comment: @user140013:  what does mod(one root) + mod(other root) mean?  I'm guessing you mean $\vert \rho_1 \vert + \vert \rho_2 \vert$, where the $\rho_i$ are the roots of $px^2 + qx + r = 0$.  A very different question indeed!  Now I have to rethink and perhaps edit my answer.  Which is, of course, OK!

Comment: I think I'm going to delete my answer because even for what I assumed, it's not correct.  The sum could be anywhere from $(-\infty, +\infty)$ (even under the constraint that we definitely have two complex roots)...because $p$ could be very small, $r$ very large and thus $q$ very large.

Comment: I believe the sum of the magnitudes of the two complex roots would just be $\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{2q^2 - 4pr}$ under the constraint that $q^2 < 4pr$ which, I think, would give a bound $\frac{\sqrt{2\cdot 4pr - 4pr}}{p} = \frac{2\sqrt{pr}}{p} = 2\sqrt{\frac{r}{p}}$.

Comment: ...but that's really no bound at all since $\sqrt{\frac{r}{p}} > 1$ means it could be very large and since that was the _upper_ bound, the sum of the magnitudes just has to be smaller than some (possibly) unbounded value.

Comment: @user140013:  my answer explains why $\vert \rho_1 \vert + \vert \rho_2 \vert > 2$.  So choice (d) is correct.

Comment: @Jared:  you might want to read my answer to this question.  Cheers!